# generating random alphabets with some alphabets having a higher frequency of occurence(vc++6.0)

Tags: c++, random, letters

basically i have a function that generates random alphabets .i have done this using the rand() function to generate numbers and them converted them to their corresponding ascii equivalents.
but i want the vowels to be generated in higher numbers as compared to other alphabets.i.e
if have generated say 10 alphabets then there should be like 2 o's,3 a's etc.
how do i do this??in vc++6.0.

**Edit:**
actually i am making scrabble as my college project in vc++6.0. so under my board i have 7 buttons on which i am displaying a random letter on each.so what i want is that ..like in scrabble we have:

```
 1 point:  E ×12, A ×9, I ×9, O ×8, N ×6, R ×6, T ×6, L ×4, S ×4, U ×4
 2 points: D ×4, G ×3
 3 points: B ×2, C ×2, M ×2, P ×2
 4 points: F ×2, H ×2, V ×2, W ×2, Y ×2
 5 points: K ×1
 8 points: J ×1, X ×1
10 points: Q ×1, Z ×1
```

so just like you would pick 7 random letters from the above described set, i want the 7 letters to be generatd in the same way.

Comment: alphabet = letter? alphabet is a set of letters

Answer (score 1):

You could add another rand function.
F.e. (sorry, this is just pseudo code)

```
if(rand(0,10) >= 5) {
    //generate here a vowel at random
} else {
    //generate a normal letter or a random letter (including vowel)
}
```

This will generate vowels at a 50/50 chance, you can change this chance by altering the 5.

Bobby

Comment: actually i am making  scrabble as my college project in vc++6.0.
so under my board i have 7 buttons on which i am displaying a random letter on each.so what i want is that ..like in scrabble we have..
1 point: E ×12, A ×9, I ×9, O ×8, N ×6, R ×6, T ×6, L ×4, S ×4, U ×4
2 points: D ×4, G ×3
3 points: B ×2, C ×2, M ×2, P ×2
4 points: F ×2, H ×2, V ×2, W ×2, Y ×2
5 points: K ×1
8 points: J ×1, X ×1
10 points: Q ×1, Z ×1

so just like you would pick 7 random letters from the above described set, i want the 7 letters to be generatd in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

give every value a weight. E.g. a=5, b=5, c=2, .... q=1, z=2  etc

the higher the weight, the more often you want the letter to appear

to calc a random letter, add all the weights together and pick a random between 0 and the totalweight.

then select the letter which corresponds with the drawn number:

as in the example:
if you drew 0-4 you take the a, if you drew 5-9 you take b, 10-11 =c  etc etc

Comment: actually i am making  scrabble as my college project in vc++6.0.
so under my board i have 7 buttons on which i am displaying a random letter on each.so what i want is that ..like in scrabble we have..
1 point: E ×12, A ×9, I ×9, O ×8, N ×6, R ×6, T ×6, L ×4, S ×4, U ×4
2 points: D ×4, G ×3
3 points: B ×2, C ×2, M ×2, P ×2
4 points: F ×2, H ×2, V ×2, W ×2, Y ×2
5 points: K ×1
8 points: J ×1, X ×1
10 points: Q ×1, Z ×1

so just like you would pick 7 random letters from the above described set, i want the 7 letters to be generatd in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial solution is to use 2 lists. One with the vowels and one with consonants.
Now construct your new alphabet by selecting N random vowels and M random consonants where N > M and N+M = max size of alphabet.

Comment: actually i am making  scrabble as my college project in vc++6.0.
so under my board i have 7 buttons on which i am displaying a random letter on each.so what i want is that ..like in scrabble we have..
1 point: E ×12, A ×9, I ×9, O ×8, N ×6, R ×6, T ×6, L ×4, S ×4, U ×4
2 points: D ×4, G ×3
3 points: B ×2, C ×2, M ×2, P ×2
4 points: F ×2, H ×2, V ×2, W ×2, Y ×2
5 points: K ×1
8 points: J ×1, X ×1
10 points: Q ×1, Z ×1

so just like you would pick 7 random letters from the above described set, i want the 7 letters to be generatd in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I'll write it in pseudo-code. Let's say you have your letter frequencies defined:

```
freq['a'] = 0.2
freq['b'] = 0.01
...
freq['z'] = 0.02
```

Sum of all elements should obviously be 1.

Then you can define an array with intervals:

```
intr['a'] = [0; 0.2)
intr['b'] = [0.2; 0.01)
...
intr['z'] = [0.98; 1)
```

Then when you generate a random number `n` in interval `[0; 1)`, you just need to run through interval array and find which letter corresponds to that:

```
for(letter = 'a' .. 'z')
  if n in intr[letter] then return letter;
```

The interval array can also be implemented using integer numbers for speed.

Comment: actually i am making  scrabble as my college project in vc++6.0.
so under my board i have 7 buttons on which i am displaying a random letter on each.so what i want is that ..like in scrabble we have..
1 point: E ×12, A ×9, I ×9, O ×8, N ×6, R ×6, T ×6, L ×4, S ×4, U ×4
2 points: D ×4, G ×3
3 points: B ×2, C ×2, M ×2, P ×2
4 points: F ×2, H ×2, V ×2, W ×2, Y ×2
5 points: K ×1
8 points: J ×1, X ×1
10 points: Q ×1, Z ×1

so just like you would pick 7 random letters from the above described set, i want the 7 letters to be generatd in the same way.